# Select item in dropdown needs to show / hide another dropdown

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have a dropdown and when I select 'Arrangement' then the other dropdown needs to be visible.
When you select an other field again the second dropdown needs to "reset/no selection".

How can I do this?

**The HTML:**

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
  <tr>
    <td>Select:</td>
    <td align="right">
    <select name="mydropdown" class="formfield">
        <option value="">No selection</option>
        <option value="Diner">Diner</option>
        <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
        <option value="Arrangement">Arrangement</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="go-hide">
    <td>Type arrangement</td>
    <td align="right">
    <select class="formfield">
        <option value="">No selection</option>
        <option value="All you can eat Tapas">All you can eat Tapas</option>
        <option value="High Tea">High Tea</option>
        <option value="Combinaties">Combinations</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Example here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/R555U/1/

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#keuze').change(function () {
        if ($('#keuze option:selected').text() == "Arrangement"){
            $('.go-hide').hide();
            $('#arrangement').show();
            $('#combinatie option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
        } else if ($('#keuze option:selected').text() == "Combinatie"){
            $('.go-hide').hide();
            $('#combinatie').show();
            $('#arrangement option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
        } else {
            $('.go-hide').hide();
            $('#arrangement option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
            $('#combinatie option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
        } });

});
```